# Flatten Laravel Eloquent Collection relationships

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, flatten

I am using the following database structure:

movie
   - id
   - title

director
   - id
   - name

movie_director
   - director_id
   - movie_id

The models are set up like this:

Movie.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Movie extends Model
{
    public $table = "movie";

    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function directors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Director', 'movie_director');
    }
}
```

Director.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Director extends Model
{
    public $table = "director";

    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie', 'movie_director');
    }
}
```

So there is a many-to-many relationship between a movie and a director.

On the detail page of a movie I would like to post other movies of the directors of the original movie.

```
    $movie = Movie::with('directors.movies')->find(1);
```

That gives me all the data I need, but to get a complete list of movies I would have to loop through the directors collection and then loop through the movies collection inside that director. Isn't there a faster/easier way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just use flatten or flatMap on it as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods ?

Comment: Yes, I could do something like this: 

`$movies = $movie->directors->flatMap(function ($val) {return $val->movies; });`
 
But what if you needed to go another level, or maybe 2 levels deeper? Then you would need to nest multiple of those flatMap functions. I was really hoping there was an easier way, for example by using the dot notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to do this would be to add a method to your `Movie` model using `hasManyThrough` to get the other movies related by director.

```
public function relatedMovies()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Movie', 'App\Director');
}
```

Then separately eager load that relationship, rather than eager loading the nested relationship.

```
$movie = Movie::with('directors', 'relatedMovies')->find(1);
```